# Replace value in HTML based on option "label" attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to *replace* a value on the page based on what is selected in a dropdown. More specifically I need to fill in the "label" value. Here's the HTML:

```
<select class="item-number">
  <option>Please select</option>
  <option value="123" label="Description about 123">123</option>
  <option value="456" label="Description about 456">456</option>
</select>

<span class="item-name">Description shows up here</span>
```

Now, if someone selects, say, option 123, I would need the text in the `span` to be replaced with "Description about 123". Is there a way to achieve this? I'm a JS/Jquery newbie and completely out of my depth here. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straight from [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/)

```
$("select").change(function () {
    var str = "";
    $(".item-number option:selected").each(function (i) {
        if ($(this).attr('label')) 
            str = $(this).attr('label');
        else 
            str = "Description shows up here ";
    });
    $(".item-name").text(str);
}).trigger('change');
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kks9x/2/)**

Make some changes to the above one to make it work more better :)

**UPDATE 1**(*on OP's request*):

```
$('select').on('change',function(){
   label= $(this).find(':selected').val();
   $('.item-name').text(label);
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EZRXX/2/)**

**UPDATE 2**:

```
$("select").change(function () {
    var str = "";
    str = $(".item-number option:selected").val();
    if (str == "Please select") {
        $(".no-add").show();
        $(".add").hide();
    } else {
        $(".no-add").hide();
        $(".add").show();
    }
    $(".item-name").text(str);
}).trigger("change");
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kks9x/4/)**

Comment: Thanks very much, this works great too! If I decide NOT to use the label but the standard option value, how would I change the code? Also, I'd like to hide/show a button that allows users to add their selection to a cart. I've added some HTML here http://jsfiddle.net/EZRXX/1. Would you be so kind as to point me in the right direction? THANK YOU! :)

Comment: That is perfect, thanks! Can you just help me get the "add to cart" button right? I've tried this here, but it's not working 100% yet: http://jsfiddle.net/2MHSz/ Thanks so much!!!

Comment: @KaiBrach Check this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kks9x/4/). You can make modifications to it to make it better :).

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.item-number').change(function () {
    var lbl = $(this.options[this.selectedIndex]).attr('label');
    $('.item-name').html(lbl);
});
```

here's the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vonDy2791/SggGD/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).on('change','select.item-number', function() {
    $('.item-name').text($(this).find(':selected').attr('label'));
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CarloOV/SggGD/1/)

Answer (score 0):

It's that simple:

```
$("select.item-number").on("change", function() {
    $(".item-name").text($(this).find(":selected").attr("label"));
});
```

Fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/9YLZF/

Cheers!